# SQL Server Linked Server loses login-mapping

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server

I have two SQL Server machines, server A and server B. There is a stored procedure (sp_A) on server A, it needs to read data from server B, so I created a linked server for server B on server A. So far, everything is ok.

Now I have a application which needs to use the data of server A, and it uses ODBC datesource, so I created a odbc DSN for server A. When this application call sp_A, this error shows up:

> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists

Answer (score 0):

In your linked server properties (on the *Security* tab) you can specify an alternative login for logins not definded in the local server logins.

Specify the login you used for your ODBC DSN.